# How can I set a Speed to a "moveTo" method in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Hey :) i want to create my first Game App in Swift and have a problem.
In the Screen should be two balls at each side. When i'm touch the display they move to the position of the other ball. When i'm stop touching the display it should stay at the position where it is.

I tried it with the "moveTo" method, but i don't want that it needs the "duration" time from each position. Is there something like "Speed" even if the ball is in the middle or 3/4 of the screen (on x-position)?

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    leftBall.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: frame.maxX - rightBall.size.width * 2, duration: 2))
    rightBall.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: frame.minX + leftBall.size.width * 2, duration: 2))
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    leftBall.removeAllActions()
    rightBall.removeAllActions()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge in that SKAction-stuff, but:

Speed is by definition distance divided by time. In other words: time (=duration) is distance divided by speed.

You could build a simple function with distance and speed as arguments returning a duration.

Maybe something like this?:

```
  func duration(speed: Double, distance: Double) -> Double {
    return distance/speed
  }

  let someSpeed: Double = 2.0 // = 2px/timebase
  let someDistance: Double = 1.0 // this value can be fixed in fact inside the function becaus it is just some kind of "resolution"

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    leftBall.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: ballsOldPosition.x+someDistance, duration: duration(speed: someSpeed, distance: someDistance)))
  }
```

Or am I missing something in your question?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here for a simple Sprite-Kit app with constant speed movement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45694380/1430420 and look at the code controlling the missiles' movement.

Baiscally you have a property to define the object's speed:

```
let missileSpeed: CGFloat = 800 // Points per second)
```

and then a helper function to calculate how long it will take the object to travel to it's destination at it's given speed:

```
let missileFlightTime = travelTime(to: missileDestination, from: ship.position, at: missileSpeed)
```

and here's the helper function:

```
func travelTime(to target : CGPoint, from start : CGPoint, at speed : CGFloat) -> TimeInterval {
   let distance = hypot(target.x - start.x, target.y - start.y)
   return TimeInterval(distance/speed)
    }
```

and then define the `moveTo` SKAction using the calculated time:

```
let missileMove = SKAction.move(to: missileDestination,
                                duration: TimeInterval(missileFlightTime))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ball has a SKPhysicsBody, then you can set the velocity instead of using actions

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    leftBall.physicsBody!.velocity = CGPoint(x:frame.maxX - rightBall.size.width * 2,y:0.0)
    rightBall.physicsBody!.velocity = CGPoint(x:frame.maxX - rightBall.size.width * 2,y:0.0)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    leftBall.physicsBody!.velocity = CGPoint.zero
    rightBall.physicsBody!.velocity = CGPoint.zero
}
```

You are going to have to turn off linearDamping, friction, and gravity if you want the ball to move forever.

Also, you are probably going to have to play with the numbers since velocity is based on meters, not points