# Sprite Node position not updating with touch?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Essentially, what I want is for when I touch a node, I want to be able to move it across the screen. The problem is that whenever I move my finger too fast, the node just stops following it.

The spriteNodes in particular that I'm trying to do this with have physics bodies and animating textures so I tried to do the same code with a completely plain spriteNode and I've encountered the same problem.

The code that I have here is pretty simple so I'm not sure if this is a problem with what I've written or if it's just a lag problem that I can't fix. It's also basically the same all throughout touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded

```
for touch in touches {

  let pos = touch.location(in: self)
  let node = self.atPoint(pos)

  if node.name == "activeRedBomb"{
    node.position = pos
  }

  if node.name == "activeBlackBomb"{
    node.position = pos
  }


  if node.name == "test"{
    node.position.x = pos.x
    node.position.y = pos.y
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that if you move your finger too fast, then at some point, the touch location will no longer be on the sprite, so you code to move the node won't fire.

What you need to do is set a flag in `touchesBegan()` to indicate that this sprite is touched, move the sprite to the location of the touch in `touchesMoved()` if the flag is set and then reset the flag in `touchesEnded()`.

Here's roughly what you need to add for this:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var bombIsTouched = false

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        if activeRedBomb.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
            bombIsTouched = true
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if bombIsTouched {
        activeRedBomb.position = (touches.first?.location(in: self))!
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if bombIsTouched {
        bombIsTouched = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using a reference variable instead.  This would allow him to move many different types of sprites without having  a huge branch statement

Comment: Yeah - this was just a quick example taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45694380/1430420 hastily modified, which is why I didn't use the OP's node selection by name.

Comment: No, i mean don’t use the boolean, use `var nodeTouched : SKNode?`  and on begins use `nodeTouched = activeRedBomb`